# Flow of system of differential equations and monodromy operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Given
$$
    \dot{y}
    =
    A(t)y,\quad
    A(t)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 + \frac{\cos t}{2 + \sin t} & 0 \\
    1 & -1
    \end{pmatrix},
    \quad y\in\mathbb{R}^2,
$$

I am supposed to calculate the flow $\Phi^{t,0}$, then calculate the monodromy operator $M$ as $M=\Phi^{2\pi,0}$, and then confirm that
$$ M=e^{2\pi\Omega},\quad\Omega=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\\frac{4}{5} & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$

I did all this, but my calculation of $M$ is different from what I'm supposed to confirm.

The steps/assumptions I made:

1. $\Phi^{t,0}=\Psi(t)[\Psi(0)]^{-1}$, where $\Psi(t)$ is the fundamental matrix of $A(t)$.
2. To get the fundamental matrix, I first solved the first equation of the system, which is $\frac{dy_1}{dt}=A_{11}\cdot y_1$ using separation of variables, and then the second equation $\frac{dy_2}{dt}=A_{21}y_1-A_{22}y_2$, inwhich I could fill in $y_1$, using Lagrange's variation of constants. I now got expressions for $y_1$ and $y_2$ in terms of $y_{1,0}$ and $y_{2,0}$ (to be clear: $y_{1,0}=y_1({t_0})$):

$$y_1=y_{1,0}\frac{1}{2}e^t(\sin(t)+2)),\quad y_2=y_{2,0}e^{-t} + y_{1,0}\frac{1}{2}(e^{t} - \frac{1}{5} e^{t} (\cos t - 2 \sin t) - \frac{4}{5}e^{-t})$$

3. So I then figured that the fundamental matrix, which consists of linearly independen solutions, must be

$$\Psi(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}e^t(\sin(t)+2) & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}(e^{t} - \frac{1}{5} e^{t} (\cos t - 2 \sin t) - \frac{4}{5}e^{-t}) & e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

(**I have confirmed that these two columns are indeed solutions to the system at the start of this question. But are they also linearly independent?**)

Now, assuming that I didn't make any miscalculations, and these steps make sense for calculating the flow, I get that

$$
M=\Phi^{2\pi,0}=\Psi(2\pi)[
\Psi(0)]^{-1}=\Psi(2\pi)[I]^{-1}=\Psi(2\pi).
$$

From this we see that $M_{12}=0$, while the topright element of $e^{2\pi\Omega}$ does not equal zero (according to Matlab Online), so I must have made a mistake in my calculations, methods, or both. **If I need to calculate the fundamental matrix in another way, or must not use the fundamental matrix to calculate the flow, please advise me on what to do.**

Comment: I do not quite understand where you see the contradiction. $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\Omega}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \mathrm{e}^{2\, \pi} & 0\\ \frac{2\, \mathrm{e}^{2\, \pi}}{5} - \frac{2\, \mathrm{e}^{- 2\, \pi}}{5} & \mathrm{e}^{- 2\, \pi} \end{array}\right),
$ which matches your expression for $\Psi(2\pi)$

Comment: @AVK How did you calculate that matrix exponential? I tried using Matlab (Image to the calculation: https://gyazo.com/29fc125a23cfe933e5f28867efc64a38) and found that the topright element (question stated topleft, but I meant topright element) of this matrix exponential is non-zero

Comment: `exp` calculates the elementwise exponential. To calculate the matrix exponential, use `expm`

Comment: O god.. Okay. I tried calculating it by hand before by rewriting $e^{2\pi\Omega}=e^{A+B}$, where $A=\begin{pmatrix}2\pi & 0 \\ 0 & -2\pi \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ \frac{4}{5}\cdot 2\pi & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, but $A$ and $B$ do not commute.